# How to add condition in pandas named aggregates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
   director_master_id  company_master_id        designation date_cessation appointment_original_date  some_col            director_name appt_chng_desig_date        t_designation t_dir_category
0             2601721            2465280           Director            NaT                2020-08-21  0000000              VINEET                  NaT             director       promoter
1             1111111            2465280           Director            NaT                2021-09-30  7129633              VIJAY                    NaT  additional director   professional
2             2222222            2465280           Director            NaT                2022-03-06  9500698              SACHDEV                 NaT  additional director   professional
3             3333333            2465280           Director            NaT                2023-01-03  9748791              SHUVI                   NaT  additional director   professional
4              444444            2465280           Director            NaT                2022-09-28  1469375            CHAKRABORTY               NaT             director    independent
5              933052            2465280           Director            NaT                2023-02-18  3565167               ANUP                   NaT                  NaN            NaN
6             2911635            2465280  Managing Director            NaT                2020-08-21  7767248              KUMAR                    NaT    managing director       promoter
7              779440            2465280           Director            NaT                2021-09-30  7298703            TYLER                      NaT  additional director   professional
8              804512            2465280           Director            NaT                2021-09-30  3559152            KARTIK                     NaT  additional director   professional
9               90320            2465280           Director            NaT                2021-09-30   177699            GOPAL                      NaT  additional director   professional
```

How to do aggregate function based on other function in pandas named aggregates? In the below given code my intention is to calculate `num_of_promoter_directors` based on the condition that `t_dir_category` should be equal to `promoter` and count only those rows. Here the result should be 2.

In the next line, I need to collect list of names based condition that column `t_designation` is `managing director` and the result should be `[KUMAR]`.

I know that i'm selecting a column on top of whioch i'm doing the aggregates and this code results in `KeyError: 't_dir_category'`

```
directors_info = director_history_details.groupby('company_master_id').agg(
                num_of_directors=('director_master_id', 'count'),
                num_of_promoter_directors=('director_master_id', lambda x: x[x['t_dir_category'] == 'promoter'].count()),
                managing_directors=('director_name',
                                    lambda x: x[x['t_designation'] == 'managing director']['director_name'].unique())
)
```

Also I know that I can calculate this individually and then join, but i'm trying to do this in a single block. Is there a way to achieve this?

expected output

```
   company_master_id  num_of_directors  num_of_promoter_directors managing_directors
0            2465280                10                          2  [Kumar, VINEET]
```

Comment: what you want to see as an output?

Comment: @ElvinJafarov, added expected output.

Comment: I updated the answer, please upvote and approve for everyone to see the solution

Comment: @ElvinJafarov, Approved and Upvoted. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
directors_info = director_history_details.groupby('company_master_id').agg(
    num_of_directors=('director_master_id', 'count'),
    num_of_promoter_directors=('t_dir_category', lambda x: (x == 'promoter').sum()),
    managing_directors=('director_name', lambda x: list(x[director_history_details['t_designation'] == 'managing director'].unique()) if (director_history_details['t_designation'] == 'managing director').any() else None)
).reset_index()
print(directors_info)
```

output :

```
 company_master_id  num_of_directors  num_of_promoter_directors managing_directors
0            2465280                10                          2            [KUMAR]
```

Comment: Thanks you!! Would you please explain what exactly are you doing in here?

Comment: This code only collects a single name, but there are two promoters and i need to get all those 2 respective names. How to implement that?

Comment: not really, VINEET is director not managing director.  If you wanna consider that too, please formulate your question differently in your post or post different question

Answer (score -2):

Use pandas.NamedAgg:

```
pd.\
    DataFrame({
        'company_master_id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
        't_dir_category': [
            'promoter', 'professional', 'professional',
            'promoter', 'promoter'
        ]
    }).\
    groupby('company_master_id').\
    agg(
        num_of_promoter_directors=pd. \
        NamedAgg(
            column="t_dir_category",
            aggfunc=lambda x:\
                (x == 'promoter').sum()
        )
    )

Out[60]: 
                   num_of_promoter_directors
company_master_id                           
1                                          1
2                                          2
```

Comment: I need to do all the 3 aggregates in one go. Also i need the third aggregate function's logic which is dependent on 2 columns